# Color selection utility application that imports directly into CSS for asp.net project.

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, windows

I am working on an ASP.NET project where I have to frequently choose color combinations for my page, being a software developer , I don't want to work as designer , thus I am looking for a tool which provide me an interface to choose colors and save css directly in my ASP.Net project, so that I can quickly change various color, click on save kind of button, refresh my page and it should show me the changes.

Currently I am browsing a site which allow me to choose a color and give me its code , then I have to open a big css file and locate the entry, and copy that color code there. This process make me lazy on choosing perfect color combination for my page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

here are some things I use: They're not automatically imported into your css, but they're about as close as you can get... just a simple copy paste away...

- http://kuler.adobe.com/ when I'm initially getting inspiration for a site.
- http://gradcolor.com/ for gradients.
- http://drpeterjones.com/colorcalc/ when i need to convert an RGB to Hex color code for css.

I'm not a designer either but I have done some side projects on my own from scratch and I find I have to design and code, these are the things I have bookmarked as "design utilitles" sites for the off chances I get stuck doing "designy" things. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use [color pic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) to grab random colors I like for my web page. You can put the pointer over any color on your screen and save it to your palette. If you select the color in the palette it will give you the rgb hex code which you can use in your css.

As for saving css, not quite sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

using the developer toolbar in ie or firefox (firebug) you should be able to find both a color picker and be able to set new colors to elements although they of course wont be saved so you can't refresh the page without losing your changes

Answer (score 0):

use a Firebug and Color Picker at the same time. Color Picker is windows program that give u the code of the color where your mouse is clicked. And with firebug you can change the color code of the website without editing your page and upload it again